# How to limit duration of the video with Dropzonejs?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, file-upload, ffmpeg

I have a form which I upload videos and duration/length of the video is important.

After I upload the file with PHP, I check the duration of the video file size with `FFMpeg`.

I calculate duration in PHP and need to send value of the duration via PHP somehow. I think I have to append the duration to `$result` variable of Json.

This is my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <script src=
        "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://rawgit.com/enyo/dropzone/master/dist/dropzone.js"></script>
        <link href="css/dropzone.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script type="text/javascript">

        Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {

        maxFiles: 1,
        acceptedFiles: "image/*,video/*",
        maxfilesexceeded: function (file) {
            this.removeAllFiles();
            this.addFile(file);
            $('#infomsg').hide();

        },

        init: function () {
            $('#infomsg').hide();

            this.on("success", function (result) {

                $('#infomsg').show();


                $("#boatAddForm").append($('<input type="hidden" ' +
                    'name="files[]" ' +
                    'value="' + result.name + '">'));

            });
        }
        };


        </script>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>
            This is the most minimal example of Dropzone. The upload in this
            example doesn't work, because there is no actual server to handle
            the file upload.
        </p><!-- Change /upload-target to your upload address -->
        <form action="/dropzone/upload.php" class="dropzone" id="my-dropzone"
        name="my-dropzone"></form>
        <form action="/dropzone/son.php" id="boatAddForm" method="post" name=
        "boatAddForm">
            <input class="submit" type="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my PHP

```
<?php
$ds          = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

$storeFolder = 'uploads';

if (!empty($_FILES)) {

    $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

    $targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . $ds. $storeFolder . $ds;

    $targetFile =  $targetPath. $_FILES['file']['name'];

    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);

} else {
    $result  = array();

    $files = scandir($storeFolder);                 //1
    if ( false!==$files ) {
        foreach ( $files as $file ) {
            if ( '.'!=$file && '..'!=$file) {       //2
                $obj['name'] = $file;
                $obj['size'] = filesize($storeFolder.$ds.$file);
                $result[] = $obj;
            }
        }
    }

    header('Content-type: text/json');              //3
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

If I could check a custom json response right after

```
 Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
```

like other requirements for success, I won't have to right if statements in success in order to check the validation.

Basically I want to do it as I do like

```
 maxFiles: 1,
```

without writing any conditions inside *success*

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you want to get duration of the video file on client-side. It is possible using HTML5  API methods. [Original example here](http://coursesweb.net/javascript/duration-audio-video-file-before-upload_cs).

There is no support for this in dropzone.js by default. You will have to add this functionality yourself.

Here is the example code to get the duration of the video upon video file selection (taken from coursesweb.net).

```
<form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  File: <input type="file" name="fup" id="fup" /><br>
  Duration: <input type="text" name="f_du" id="f_du" size="5" /> seconds<br>
  <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
<audio id="audio"></audio>

<script>
// Code to get duration of audio /video file before upload - from: http://coursesweb.net/

//register canplaythrough event to #audio element to can get duration
var f_duration =0;  //store duration
document.getElementById('audio').addEventListener('canplaythrough', function(e){
  //add duration in the input field #f_du
  f_duration = Math.round(e.currentTarget.duration);
  document.getElementById('f_du').value = f_duration;
  URL.revokeObjectURL(obUrl);
});

//when select a file, create an ObjectURL with the file and add it in the #audio element
var obUrl;
document.getElementById('fup').addEventListener('change', function(e){
  var file = e.currentTarget.files[0];
  //check file extension for audio/video type
  if(file.name.match(/\.(avi|mp3|mp4|mpeg|ogg)$/i)){
    obUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    document.getElementById('audio').setAttribute('src', obUrl);
  }
});
</script>
```